# Stop Ajax request as well as the process started on controller in Spring

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC and I have created Controllers and I am accessing them using the JQuery Ajax request, but sometimes it may be possible that the process takes long time, so I want to give the user option to stop the request for that I am using the abort function of JQuery and it stops the Ajax request successfully but it does not stop the process started on the controller. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I don't think that can be done unless you do a continuous polling for the current status or something from server

Answer (score 1):

If the request has already been sent to the server then the server will process the request even if we abort the request but the client will not wait for/handle the response.

Maybe you'll have to write some custom logic where initiate a thread in controller for each such ajax call and track their thread id. Then on abort request go back in controller and kill that thread.

Just a basic idea, I haven't implemented it myself so not sure about code/logic problems you might face.

Comment: Yes i have also thought for that but then i have to use the multi threading and also have to fetch all the threads but it will a complex and time taking task. it is a solution but i will use it as the last solution. I am searching for some more simple and feasible solution but thanks for your efforts.

Comment: just to improve lil bit on my answer - each http request is a separate thread in itself. So maybe you don't have to write custom code for multithreading. but keep registering these request threads in some static collection. and kill and unregister on abort call.

Comment: Note that killing threads can lead to any inconsistent state of your application if you are doing any writes. Recommended option is to profile your code with a profiler, optimize your code, analyze why its slow. If you are making an application where user waits waits and clicks aborts, thats something wrong in your design which is not at all user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery's abort() will stop the client to listen for the response but still the server will process.

I can think of something:(I hope the process is long enough for you to stop by the way)

- Continuous Polling using a thread. Have a status flag that reads at high frequency so that when you do an abort, you update the status of the request to stop. If continuous polling is enabled, you can check that status is now to abort and the thread is stopped or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any custom logic there is no way to stop an ongoing process at controller level. Because controller process and UI process are two different layers the only connection between them is socket request - response connection.

abort on javascript side could cause big risk for your application, backend will complete process but ui won't be aware of it. You can manage your response time on controller side and return an error and abort your controller process with your own logic. for example if you have some loop on Controller put a timecheck, or you have another socket connection like db configure your connection based on timeout parameter.

What you want to do is directly related to your controller implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable to store the ajax request

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '<*url*>',
    ......
});
```

We can use my request `.abort()`

```
req.abort();
```

Check for reference [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1)

Comment: check his question again. He's able to do that. What OP is concerned about is controller code which is already started now.

Comment: I have already used it please read my question carefully Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing this. Well, stopping response is not impossible, but will be untidy code.

Still if that is the requirement you can do it the other way. You can always keep a checking session while you are executing your controller code. A client side event (like a button click) can always trigger another ajax to set this session variable off on demand.